# Connecting TRS Mono to TRS Stereo

Tags: audio, balance

What will happen if I connect TRS Mono output on my audio interface to an unbalanced stereo input on my monitor speakers using a 1/4 TRS to 1/8 TRS cable?

Just curious, what will happen. I saw a message of a guy here (see post #2) https://www.gearslutz.com/board/newbie-audio-engineering-production-question-zone/959088-focusrite-scarlet-2i2-computer-speakers.html
saying that, under no condition should you connect a TRS mono to a stereo input via a 1/4 TRS to 1/8 TRS cable?

I thought that the only thing that will happen is that I'll get a mono signal...

Comment: Based on the given information, no-one could even guess.

Comment: Do you have any information (manual!) on whether the monitor input is balanced?

Comment: What is a "TS stereo input"? TS connections have only two conductors and can only carry one signal, so that means you cannot send or receive stereo audio with a TS connector. Are you sure you don't mean TS mono output to TRS stereo input? If you aren't sure, just edit your question to include the exact make and model of both the interface and the monitors and we will be able to tell you exactly how you can connect them.

Comment: Sorry I meant, TRS stereo, just edited the post

Comment: Does it mean, I will get a mono sound, or no sound at all?

Comment: It could be that the T and R on the Mono carry the mono signal and the S carries some sort of voltage which could cause mayhem if plugged into a TRS Stereo input.  But like everyone else has said, without more information, that's just speculation.

Comment: I mean I asked that just out of curiosity, since that guy said to avoid connecting it that way at all costs. I think the OP of that topic has Creative FPS1500 speakers and  Scarlett 2i2 audio interface.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic / too broad because it depends on the circuitry you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you connect a TRS mono (balanced) output to a TRS stereo (unbalanced) input, you'll get a strange effect. It will be sort of mono, but it will sound strange.

A mono TRS output sends the same signal on the tip and ring, but with opposite polarities. Since the stereo TRS input interprets tip and ring as left and right, you'll have the same signal on the left and right channels after the input, but with opposite polarity still. If you listen to that on headphones, it will sound strange but will mostly work. If you try to listen to it on speakers, a lot of the low frequencies are likely to cancel and it will sound strange and pretty bad.